# Получить все данные из таблицы для максимального значения одного из столбцов

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблица `table1`. Пример данных таблицы:

```
versionnum  project name  type  subtype  regnum status
         1  prl     namel typel subtypel      1 stat1
         2  prl     name2 type2 subtype2      2 stat2
         3  prl     name3 type3 subtype3      3 stat3
         4  prl     name4 type4 subtype4      4 stat4
         5  prl     name5 type5 subtype5      5 stat5
```

Необходимо вывести все данные, для максимального значения поля `versionnum`.

Каким запросом это можно получить?

Comment: `select * from table1 order by versionnum desc FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY`

Comment: ... если `versionnum` НЕ уникально - добавить `WITH TIES`.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь Топ N запросом [(см. row_limiting_clause)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6):

```
select * from table1
order by versionnum desc
fetch first rows with ties 
/

VERSIONNUM PRO NAME  TYPE  SUBTYPE      REGNUM STATU
---------- --- ----- ----- -------- ---------- -----
         5 prl name5 type5 subtype5          5 stat5
         5 pr3 name7 type7 subtype7          5 stat1
         5 pr2 name6 type6 subtype6          5 stat1
```

С тестовыми данными на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7f689c37f6b42c5ccda753c4576f56ec).